# How could we view the small size image as cover image without pixelated

Tags: html, css, image, pixel

my original image size should be any size like , 160*80 or 280 *160 1300*278

I can view that image on cover photo but it shows like very blury and pixels are elaborated

Screenshot of my cover photo.

[image]

Comment: what kind of image was it?

Comment: The stretch effect is because of you are setting both with and height.try to set anyone (width or height), you wont get a stretch image

Comment: but i want in fixed size of 1319*292 pixel .Then how can i assume the height. If i remove height it goes upto footer

Comment: png @GokulrajMahadheeraa

Comment: you can use a high-resolution image which doesn't drop its quality even when it shrinks, or if having a low-resolution image to fit for higher resolution property it will blur.

Comment: Try SVG if possible. link --- https://vectormagic.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try inserting your image as a background-image with css and add the property

```
background-image: url(path);
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

If you use a relative path, be aware that you start from the folder where the css file is in.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-image: url(https://abs.twimg.com/icons/apple-touch-icon-192x192.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: background-image:url({$campaign.image});background-size: contain;height:292px;  i added this on div. But the image repeated. If i added background-image:url({$campaign.image}) no-repeat; image does not shown

Comment: Sure, you have to disable repeating. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.image-wrapper {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-image: url(https://abs.twimg.com/icons/apple-touch-icon-192x192.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation alongside your code example.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap is the most commonly used image format on the web. All your JPEG and PNG files are Bitmap image files. A bitmap image is made up of thousands of pixels. If you zoom in you can actually see those pixels as squares.
Pixels in a bitmap image
Each of these pixels is mapped to a fixed location on the image, hence the name Bitmap.
Most image editing software shrink or enlarge these pixels to resize an image. This is why when you resize an image to a smaller size there is no visible quality loss. Mainly because those pixels become even less visible.
On the other hand when you resize an image to make it large, these enlarged pixels become more visible which makes the image look blurry and pixelated.

The only solution is use an image with higher resolution means instead of 160*80 use 800x300 or so for covers :)

**If you still want to use small images as covers then use them as repeat backgrounds: [Repeat backgrounds](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)**

Comment: Yes clear explanation but if i use repeat backgroud it shows like multiple images

Comment: Yeah, it will. There is no other way you can do this. Any small image when stretched will lose its quality. Use a bigger image or repeat it. You can also decrease its opacity which will decrease the blurry pixelete effect but the image will become less visible.